# Remove category by ID in entire store

Tags: javascript, magento-1

I create a new category in Magento admin **On Sale (ID: 54)**, I select NO in Include in Navigation Menu, but even if this category is not display in desktop top navigation, I see this category in the mobnav menu, in search ... How I can hide this category completely in frontend?

Comment: rebuild the indexes

Comment: yes, without no success, so there is a custom extension for search in categories, and I see this category there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the collection code for mobile Navigation and add the category filter "include_in_menu" in that.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1) //only active categories
->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1)
```

Comment: Or you can deactivate that category and wherever you want just load that category by id